# How to import CSV file and insert data into multiple tables using codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, csv

I need to import a single csv file having data's of two linked MYSQL table using codeigniter.On import the two tables should be reflected.For example table 1 is of member data and table 2 is of each member's various details,ie each member may have more than 1 record in the table 2.

Anybody with suggestion.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$row = 1;
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p>=========================================== $num fields in line $row: ===========================================<br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',false);
?>
```

The above code helped me,this worked fine after adding some of the requirements of mine.