# How to import multiple csv files to mysql using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in a project where I need to upload multiple csv file's data to a single table in database.
Currently I have written code where I am uploading the zip file which contains csv files and extracting it in a temp folder. But I am not able to write code where it reads each csv files and insert data into mysql.
Kindly guide me.

Here is my controller code

```
public function upload() {
    $spcode = $this->input->post("spcode");
    $config['upload_path']  = './adsl/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('upload_wholesale', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}

public function fetchFilesFromDirectory() {
    $dir = "./adsl/";
    $filesArr = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
    if(!empty($filesArr)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        foreach($filesArr as $fileName) {
            $file = "./adsl/".$fileName;
            chmod($file,0777);
            if ($zip->open($file) === TRUE) {
                $zip->extractTo('./wholesaleUploads/');
                $zip->close();
                $chunkFile = explode(".", $fileName);
                $extracted_files = directory_map("./wholesaleUploads/".$chunkFile[0]);
                chmod($extracted_files,0777);


                    if ($this->csvimport->get_array($extracted_files)) {
                        $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($extracted_files);
                        //print_r($csv_array);
                        if(!empty($csv_array)) {
                             foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                                $insert_data = array(
                                    'accountNumber'=>$row['AccountNumber'],
                                    'custId'=>$row['CustID'],
                                    'serviceNumber'=>$row['ServiceNumber'],
                                    'serviceType'=>$row['Service Type'],
                                    'chargeType'=>$row['ChargeType'],
                                    'details'=>$row['Details'],
                                    'dateFrom'=>$row['DateFrom'],
                                    'dateTo'=>$row['DateTo'],
                                    'charge'=>$row['Charge'],
                                    'gst'=>$row['GST'],
                                    'payment'=>$row['Payment'],
                                    'invoiceNumber'=>$row['InvoiceNumber'],
                                    'spcode'=>$spcode,
                                );

                                $this->upload_adsl->insert_csv($insert_data);
                            }
                        }
                            $this->upload_adsl->addFiles($chunkFile[0].".csv");
                            unlink($file); // Remove from Resource Directory.
                            unlink($extracted_files); // Remove from Upload Directory.
                            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
                    }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` will not show you any error you have got. **BAD IMPLEMENTATION**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file and insert data into multiple tables using codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497083/how-to-import-csv-file-and-insert-data-into-multiple-tables-using-codeigniter)

Comment: Thanks for the information however both questions are different I am not asking to insert it in muliple tables. My question is about importing multiple csv files into 1 table.